# Keras LSTM problem, how set up correctly a neural network for time series?

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

i'm trying to undestand how lstm works for predict time series with Keras.
Here's my example.
I use an accelerometer and i have a 128.000 time series. I thought to take:
n_steps_in = 10.000
n_steps_out = 5.000 to predict.

I split the big series in 114 samples, 10.000 time series and 1 feature
X = [114, 10.000, 1]
y = [114, 5.000 ]

i'm trying to understand how many hidden layer to use, how many neurons.
Being a regression i thought to use

```
activation=ReLU, 
loss = mse
optimizer=adam
```

The problem is that many time i got loss equal nan and i can't understand why.

This i s a sample of my code

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model1.add(Dense(n_steps_out))
model1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

i'll hope that someone got some tips, thanks!!

Comment: how many epochs and what is your batch size ?

Comment: i tried with 100 epochs, batch_size 32 (default value of fit function of keras)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try fixing it by adding an activation function to your output layer:

```
model.add(Dense(n_steps_out, activation='linear'))
```

**However**

Getting nan when training usually means `Exploding Gradient`.

> In deep networks or recurrent neural networks, error gradients can
>   accumulate during an update and result in very large gradients. These
>   in turn result in large updates to the network weights, and in turn,
>   an unstable network. At an extreme, the values of weights can become
>   so large as to overflow and result in NaN values.

Check [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/exploding-gradients-in-neural-networks/) post in machine learning mastery. It will give you a very good overview of what the problem is and few potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Although LSTM is widely used for sequential data representation,Among non-deep-learning classifiers, XGBoost achieved the best results